# Validate AspectJ pointcut syntax

Tags: java, aspectj, annotation-processing

As the title suggest, is there any way to validate pointcut syntax using for example *annotatoion processor (APT)* ?

It is quite easy to get value from @Pointcut(value) using APT ...  But after that, there is a problem for me to validate if given String **matches the valid syntax** for AspectJ weaver ...

Comment: What about compiling the aspect ?

Comment: I don't think the "recommendation" close vote is justified. The OP is asking how to perform a calculation generally.

Answer (score 4):

AspectJ includes a type `org.aspectj.weaver.patterns.PatternParser`. Call the constructor with the text of your pointcut then call `getPointcut()` to retrieve a pointcut object - it will throw exceptions if there is a problem parsing your input text as a pointcut. However this is purely a syntax check on your text, it does not verify/resolve type references (but you suggest you don't need to go that far).  There are resolve methods on the pointcut object if you want to get into resolution.